# Predicting height of a person using one image

Tags: 3d, means, python, programming

I am trying to predict the height of a person from a single picture.
I discovered that the length between the knuckles of a person and the ground is between 60-65 cm and this can be used as the constant.
As we know the measurement of one distance between two points of a picture hence we should be able to predict the distance between other points.

But it doesn't seem to work:

```
# I am using Media-Pipe Module: please advise if there is any other better module which I can use
# Media Pipe module is to predict the pose of the person
```

[image: Code for loading the image]

[image: Code for drawing the predicted pose]

[image: The image of a person with the pose estimation]

[image: First part to estimate distance between two points. Second to extract values from all joints]

```
elbow_to_shoulder = (calculate_distance(l_elbow,l_shoulder) + calculate_distance(r_elbow,r_shoulder))/2
print(elbow_to_shoulder)

mean_of_legs = ((calculate_distance(l_hip,l_knee) + calculate_distance(l_knee,l_ankle) + calculate_distance(l_ankle,l_heel)) + (calculate_distance(r_hip,r_knee) + calculate_distance(r_knee,r_ankle) + calculate_distance(r_ankle,r_heel)))/2
print(mean_of_legs)
```

[image: Certain values set already]

[image: Predicted height code]

This is where the measured height is actually 168 cm but according to this prediction it is 119cm
[[image: 3D Model][7]]

[image: Media Pipe official]

Comment: This seems like more of a software issue than a mathematics issue?

Comment: There is no software issue that's the point - We can observe that the software is doing everything right. But still, the distance isn't working.